# Labels and legend in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I 'm getting the  following problem by label and legend of figures.

Please see figures.

1- legend are to long to adjust in figure. How can i make them small (-line of legend)

2- lower portion of xlabeltrick is croped.

3- Xlabel (Datum) cann't be seen.

[image: Blockquote]

Comment: can you post your plot code?

Comment: for the legend, have you tried [some of these](http://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+file+exchange+legend) ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`legendflex`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31092) for the legend and [`subaxis`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot) for the axes windows (it allows you to manipulate margin, spacing and padding). For example, you can use `subaxis` like this:

```
subaxis(1, 1, 1,'mb', .2, 'pb', .1)
```

to set the bottom margin to .2 and the bottom padding to .1. I believe a larger padding will expand the space you need.

`legendflex` allows you to adjust the horizontal length of the symbol column.